# Change "Custom Text" field value

Tags: views, 8

In Drupal 8, I created a view containing a *Custom Text* field. I want to alter/change its content for each row I get after running some code. I tried implementing `hook_views_pre_render()` and `template_preprocess_views_view_fields()`, but I wasn't able to access this field.

I also would like to learn when this *nothing* field is added to the view output, and after which hook.

Comment: For whatever reason seems like "nothing" can't be accessed. You could add some other field again and use that instead, or you could create a custom variable in hook_preprocess_views_view_fields and then print the variable in your views-view-fields--[view-name].html.twig file.

Answer (score 3):

To extend and clarify Saud Alfadhli's answer for others (I'm not allowed to comment yet), hook_preprocess_views_view_field (hook_preprocess_views_view_fields with the "s" exists as well) works great for this. Both the view ID, display ID, and field ID can be easily inferred from this hook, and the field output can easily get overwritten (as both a string or render array). Here's a quick example replacing all occurrences of my second custom text field with a simple string:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_preprocess_views_view_field().
 */
function hook_preprocess_views_view_field(&$variables) {
  if ($variables['view']->id() === 'my_view_id' && $variables['field']->options['id'] === 'nothing_2') {
    $variables['output'] = 'Hi Mom!';
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do this with a lot of (Views) hooks, but with no luck because of the (nothing) field seems not part of the entity data.

Finally I managed to alter that value by implementing theme `template_preprocess_views_view_fields()` in my module.

```
/**
 * Implements template_preprocess_views_view_fields().
 */
function MODULENAME_preprocess_views_view_field(&$vars) {
  // Print all available fields.
  foreach ($vars['view']->field as $key => $field) {
    // We will print the field name.
    print $key . '<HR>';
  }
  exit;

  // To access current row entity.
  $entity = $vars['row']->_entity;
  $entity_id = $entity->id();

  // To access entities from relationship.
  $entities = $vars['row']->_relationship_entities;

  // When you find your field key use this code below.
  if(isset($vars['view']) && ($vars['view']->id() == 'VIEW_MACHINE_NAME') && ($vars['view']->current_display == 'DISPLAY_MACHINE_NAME')) {
    if (isset($vars['view']->field) && (count($vars['view']->field) > 0)) {
      // if ($vars['field']->field == 'YOUR_FIELD_NAME')
      if ($vars['field']->field == 'nothing') {
        $vars['output'] =  [
          '#markup' => 'WRITE_NEW_VALUE_HERE_OR_CHANGE_THIS_RENDERABLE_ARRAY_TO_RENDERABLE_IMAGE_OR_WHATEVERY_YOU_WANT',
        ];
      }
    }
  }
}
```